# May I use a phrasal verb as an adjective, like "commented out code"?

Tags: adjectives, phrasal-verbs, past-participles

I'd like to express that some old code that has been commented out should be removed. May I phrase it as follows?

> Remove old, commented out code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you may. However, it is conventional to hyphenate the phrase:

> Remove old, commented-out code.

This is not strictly required, and you will often see the hyphen omitted; but it is a courtesy to the reader, to make the syntax clearer.